# How to make expanded and square alike img widget

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to make expanded & square "cell" at the same time but can't find some kind of similar stuff in [layout tutorial](https://flutter.io/tutorials/layout/) or in source code. Is it possible?

[image: screen]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'model.dart';
import 'package:flutter/painting.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: new ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
            ),
        home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
        );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
            title: new Text(widget.title),
            ),
        drawer: new Menu(),
        body: new Container(
          child: new Center(
            child: new G()
          ),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
        ),
        );
  }
}


class Menu extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Drawer(
      child: new ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          new DrawerHeader(
            child: new Text('Header'),
          ),
          new ListTile(
            title: new Text('Play'),
            onTap: () {},
          ),
          new ListTile(
            title: new Text('Do some'),
            onTap: () {},
          ),
          new ListTile(
            title: new Text('Exit'),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      elevation: 2.0,
    );
  }
}

class G extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  State createState() => new GState();
}

class Cell extends StatelessWidget {
  final Color background;
  Cell(this.background):super();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return
      new ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: new BoxConstraints.expand(),
          child: new DecoratedBox(
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
              image: new DecorationImage(
                image: new AssetImage('images/r_w2.png'),
                fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
              ),
              border: new Border.all(color: Colors.purple),
              boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[new BoxShadow(color: background)],
            ),
          ),
      );
  }
}

class GState extends State<G>{
  final ChessModel chessModel = new ChessModel();
  final Color grey = Colors.blueGrey;
  final Color white = Colors.white12;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int size = ChessModel.FIELD_SIZE;
    List<Widget> columns = generateList(size, (int i) => new Expanded(child: buildColumn(i, size)));
    return new Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: columns,
    );
  }

  List<Widget> generateList (int size, f) {
    return new List<Widget>.from(new List<int>.generate(size, (i) => i+1).map(f));
  }

  Color getBGColorByIndexes(int y, int x) {
    return (y%2 == 0 && x%2 != 0)  || (y%2 != 0 && x%2 == 0) ? grey: white;
  }
  Column buildColumn(int indexX,  int size) {
    List<Widget> cells = generateList(size, (int indexY) => new Expanded(child: new Cell(getBGColorByIndexes(indexY, indexX))));
    return new Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: cells
    );
  }
}
```

P.S.S: is there any big opensource project on flutter(>~5k lines)?

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Comment: Please read [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Comment: Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) before attempting to ask more questions.

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) The answer, *"A lot. An absurd amount. More than you think you are capable of. After you have reached the end of your rope and the pain of not having the answer exceeds the vast amount of shame received by posting your question, that's when you can go ahead and ask. Because at that point, you will have done whatever research necessary to make it a good question worth asking."*

Comment: @JarrodRoberson i'm read all of you posted, so what actually wrong in my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need scrolling, you can use [`Row`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Row-class.html) and [`Column`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Column-class.html) to lay out items evenly in each dimension. Wrap the items you want to be evenly sized in an [`Expanded`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html).

If you do want scrolling, try a [`GridView`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/GridView-class.html).

P.S. [Fuchsia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Fuchsia) is a large open source project that uses Flutter. That kind of question isn't a good candidate for Stack Overflow though.

Comment: yep, thats how I did(row+columns & expanded), but in this case 'cell' looks like rectangle where sides not equals.

Comment: You can use an AspectRatio

Comment: just found how this did in Fuchsia, they just limit top container to square like form. : `Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;  new Container(
          constraints: new BoxConstraints(
              minHeight: min(size.height, size.width) * 0.9,
              maxHeight: min(size.height, size.width) * 0.9,
              minWidth: min(size.height, size.width) * 0.9,
              maxWidth: min(size.height, size.width) * 0.9),
          `